# Modeling exchange in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, algebra, domain-model

I'm new to Haskell, and I'm looking to model stock exchange library. It's meant to be a library, hence specifics to be defined by the user. The way I intend to use this is to have users define things like this.

```
data MyExchange = MyExchange { name :: ExchangeName
                             , base :: Currency
                             , quote :: Currency }
                             deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Exchange MyExchange

data MyExchangeBookMessage = 
        MyExchangeBookMessage { time :: Time
                              , exchange :: MyExchange
                              , price :: Price 
                              , side :: Side
                              , amount :: Maybe Amount }
                              deriving (Eq, Show)

instance ExchangeBookMessage MyExchangeBookMessage
```

I've tried the following, but immediately ran into some limitations of type classes. Below is the code and the error message. Specifically what are the alternatives to parameterizing type classes with multiple types?

Here is the code for the library

```
module Lib where

data Side = Buy | Sell deriving (Eq, Show)

newtype Amount = Amount Rational deriving (Eq, Show)

newtype Price = Price Rational deriving (Eq, Show)

newtype Currency = Currency String deriving (Eq, Show)

newtype Time = Time Integer deriving (Eq, Show)

type ExchangeName = String

class Exchange a where
  name :: a -> ExchangeName
  base :: a -> Currency
  quote :: a -> Currency


class Message a where
  time :: a -> Time

class (Message a, Exchange e) => ExchangeMessage a e where
  exchange :: a -> e

class ExchangeMessage a b => BookMessage a b where
  price :: a -> Price
  side :: a -> Side
  amount :: a -> Maybe Amount
```

And the error message:

```
src/Lib.hs:22:1: error:
    • Too many parameters for class ‘ExchangeMessage’
      (Use MultiParamTypeClasses to allow multi-parameter classes)
    • In the class declaration for ‘ExchangeMessage’
```

Later I would like to be able to implement type classes like this:

```
class Strategy s where
  run (Message m, Action a) => s -> m -> a
```

In the `Strategy` implementations the `run` function will take an abstract message m, pattern match it against relevant `Message` data constructors and return specific action.

I'm porting some Scala code. in Scala I was using a hierarchy of traits with concrete case classes at the bottom:

```
trait Exchange { 
  def name: String
  def base: Currency
  def quote: Currency 
}

case class MyExchange(base: Currency, quote: Currency) {
  val name = "my-exchange"
}

trait Message {
  def time: Long
}

trait ExchangeMessage extends Message {
  def exchange: Exchange
}

trait BookMessage extends ExchangeMessage {
  def price: Double
  def side: Side
  def amount: Option[Double]
}

case class MyBookMessage(time: Long, price: Double, side: Side, amount: Option[Double]) {
  def exchange: Exchange = MyExchange(...)
}
```

Comment: There is a suggestion to `Use MultiParamTypeClasses to allow multi-parameter classes`, I suggest you take it.  Put `{-# LANGAUGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}` on the first line of the file to enable it.

Comment: This will "work", but you will run into other problems when you attempt to use any methods of `BookMessage`.  I'm not sure what `b` is supposed to be there...

Comment: @luqui: `BookMessage` extends `ExchangeMessage`: `b` is the type of the `Exchange` that comes from `ExchangeMessage`.

Comment: @luqui: I'm not sure if this is an optimal way to model this domain. I will resort to `MultiParamTypeClasses` if there is no better way to deal with this.

Comment: Your classes serve no purpose. Just use functions.

Comment: Something else came to mind:  Haskell is not an OO language, so the transition can be tough.  A technique you might try, since your brain isn't used to functional modeling, is writing some of the client code of your library directly, and then refactoring until you find the library that it should be using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First order of business, take GHC's suggestion and enable `MultiParamTypeCLasses` at the top of the file.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
```

This is a very common extension, and it will fix the immediate problem.

*However* there appear to be some modeling issues and if you proceed with this design you will surely hit some problems you didn't expect.  I can go into all the details of what your code means, but I'm not sure that would be very helpful.  Instead I'll just point you in the right direction, I think, which is to use `data` records instead of typeclasses.  Haskell typeclasses do not correspond to classes in other OO langauges and it confuses many beginners.  But I think you want to model it like this:

```
data Exchange = Exchange 
    { name :: ExchangeName
    , base :: Currency
    , quote :: Currency 
    }

data Message = Message
    { time :: Time }

-- etc.
```

which will simplify everything for you, and this acts more like OO classes than your model.  Keep in mind that records can have functions and other complex data structures as fields, which is how you get the analog of virtual methods, for example:

```
data MessageLogger = MessageLogger
    { log :: String -> IO () }
```

Comment: So concrete exchanges and messages from different exchanges might have varying fields, e.g.

`data MyExchange1 = MyExchange1 ExchangeName Currency Currency OpenTime CloseTime`
And
`data MyExchange2 = MyExchange2 ExchangeName Currency Currency Precision`

But I would like to run common methods on them, and treat them as I would treat abstract class in OOP. What's the analogy for this in Haskell?

Comment: @ak. that sounds like a good use of a typeclass then, I think you were just overdoing it in your model.  Start concrete, and as you notice duplication factor out into classes, which will ensure your abstractions are well-motivated.  Hard to give specific advice without seeing the duplication you are trying to avoid specifically.

Comment: I added a bit more info into the question regarding usage of these type classes. Basically I'm building a library where I define some abstract interfaces, and the specifics are coming in the user apps.

Comment: You can keep common functions by compositions too. You'll just have to extract the relevant sub-part at the calling site.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you will probably not be able to write a class instance for `ExchangeMessage`. The reason is that the `exchange` function must be able to return *any* type `e`. If you want to keep this way, you will need to provide a way to build an arbitrary exchange!

```
class Exchange a where
  name :: a -> ExchangeName
  base :: a -> Currency
  quote :: a -> Currency
  build :: Time -> a
```

This is the only possible signature for `build`, as all you can know from an exchange is that it has a `Time` you can query, and it's probably useless.

What I would think is a better design is to have concrete types for all those classes you defined. For example:

```
data Exchange = Exchange { getName  :: ExchangeName
                         , getBase  :: Currency
                         , getQuote :: Currency
                         } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Then, once you have written the functions that work with these concrete types, you can either:

- write functionsof type `MyExchange -> Exchange` for example, to adapt functions expecting an `Exchange`
- use classy lenses, so as to directly write functions that will consume abitrary types

All in all, for that kind of applications, if you want to be fancy with types I would suggest to use phantom types for your currencies, so that you'll statically enforce for example you can only compute the sum of two amounts of money using the same currency. Using typeclasses to mimic the habits of OO will not produce APIs that are nice to use or code that is clear.

Comment: @bartabelle: Would it benefit to at least have a type class that defines a function `MyExchange -> Exchange` or `MyExchangeMessage -> Message`? The reason is that I'd like to be able to take a list of messages `[Message]` and fold them in some way, where the predicate of the fold would pattern match messages against specific data constructors. Does this makes sense?

Comment: That type class might be useful, I can't really comment on your specific use case. However, creating new type classes is the exception more than the rule, see for example the [astar API](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/astar-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Graph-AStar.html). You'll notice how there are no typeclasses such as `HasNeighbors`, `Localized` or `Distanceable`. Just plain functions, and the API is really good.